# Duvida com injeção de dependências com Spring (objeto injetado retornando null)

Tags: java-ee, spring, injeção-de-dependência

boa tarde a todos.

Pessoal, tenho um probleminha que provavelmente eu deva estar errando ou esquecendo a ordem de alguma coisa.

Meu caso é que tenho um dois controladores. Um deles eu chamo de DestinationController.java e o outro de FileController.java. Vou colar as classe abaixo omitindo alguns métodos para reduzir o tamanho e ficar mais fácil de entender:

**DestinationController.java**

```
@Controller
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class DestinationController{

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DestinationController.class);

        //Injeta objetos da minha classe de serviço.
    @Autowired
    public DashboardFacade dashboardFacade;

    //Retorna o body do destino para inclusão
    @RequestMapping("destination")
    public String getMenudestination(Model model){

                //Funciona normalmente. Ou seja, ele retorna a lista para mim sem disparar exeções
        List<Destination> destinationList = dashboardFacade.getDestinationList();
        model.addAttribute("destination", destinationList);
        return "destination/destinationList";    
    }
     @ModelAttribute("destination")
     public Destination getDestinationObject() {
      return new Destination();
     }


    //Adicona um novo destino
    @RequestMapping(value="/addDestination", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView addDestination(@ModelAttribute("destination") @Valid Destination destination, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Model model){

        List<String> error = new ArrayList<>();

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            List<ObjectError> allErrors = result.getAllErrors();


            for (ObjectError objectError : allErrors) {
                String objectName = objectError.getDefaultMessage();
                error.add(objectName);
            }

            model.addAttribute("errors", error);
            model.addAttribute("validator", true);
            setnewDestination(model);

            return new ModelAndView("destination/newDestination");

        }else{
            if(destination.getCategories().getIdCategory() == -1){            
                error.add("Você precisa selecionar uma categoria.");
                model.addAttribute("errors", error);
                return new ModelAndView("destination/newDestination");

            }else{
                                //Aqui eu instancio um objeto do FileController passando um parametro (creio que aqui eu esteja usando uma abordagem errada)
                FileController fileController = new FileController();
                fileController.imageReplication(destination.getDtName());

                Category category = dashboardFacade.getCategoryId(destination.getCategories().getIdCategory());
                destination.setCategories(category);

                dashboardFacade.addDestination(destination);

                redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "O destino " + destination.getDtName() + " foi adicionado(a) com sucesso!");

                logger.info("Destino " + destination.getDtName() + " adicionado com sucesso para a agência: " + dashboardFacade.getAgency());
                return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("destination"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**FileController.java**

```
@Controller
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@RequestMapping("/file")
public class FileController {

    final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileController.class);


    @Autowired
    public DashboardFacade dashboardFacade;

        //Quando eu passo um objeto do tipo FileMeta e chamo o dashboardFacade.addImagePathTmp(pathJson); o funcionamento é normal. o dashboardFacade não me retorna nulo
    public void generateJson(FileMeta fileMeta) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String generated = gson.toJson(fileMeta);
        pathJson = new ImageJson();
        pathJson.setJson(generated);
        dashboardFacade.addImagePathTmp(pathJson);
        logger.info("Imagem adicionada.");
    }


    public Set<Image> imageReplication(String destination) {
        Set<Image> img = new HashSet<>();
        try {
                        // Aqui que mora o problema. Quando o metodo é invocado pelo outro controller (DestinationController.java) Meu dashboradFacade é nulo.
            List<ImageJson> imagePathTmpList = dashboardFacade.getImagePathTmpList();

            Gson gson = null;

            String subdomain = dashboardFacade.getAgency().getSubdomain();
            File base = new File("/home/manolo/joocebox-img/" + subdomain + "/"
                    + destination);

            for (ImageJson imageJsonList : imagePathTmpList) {
                gson = new Gson();
                FileMeta imgTmp = gson.fromJson(imageJsonList.getJson(), FileMeta.class);
                String path = base + "/" + imgTmp.getFileName();
                System.out.println(path);

            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return img;
    }
}
```

Bem, fiz alguns comentários no codigo para facilitar a visualização. Resumindo: o método `imageReplication(String destination)` quando chamado pelo meu controller **DestinationController.java** o dashbordFacade Dentro do FileController é retornado null disparando assim um nullPointerExeption.

Algume pode me tirar essa duvida de o que eu posso estar fazendo errado?

Um abraço a todos e sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é exatamente o que você colocou no comentário, você está utilizando uma abordagem errada:

**Injeção de Dependência:** Esse conceito não está sendo empregado. Você não deve instanciar na sua classe os objetos que ela precisa para trabalhar, ela deve recebê-los do Spring (Autowired). Porém, da forma que está implementado há outro problema, pois falta...

**Distribuição de responsabilidades:** Um controller é usado para responder requisições, e é isso que ele deve fazer. Um controller não deve usar o outro como utilitário para replicação de imagem, ou upload de arquivo ou o que quer que seja. O máximo da relação entre controllers é redirecionamento, mas um não instância ou recebe por injeção para usá-lo dessa forma.

**Componentização:** O ideal seria extrair o código do método `imageReplication` para outro objeto, responsável apenas pelo trabalho com imagens. Assim esse novo objeto pode ser injetado em todos os objetos que precisam dessa funcionalidade.

Do meu ponto de visto há algo mais a melhorar aqui. Ao invés de injetar o objeto diretamente no atributo da classe, é mais interessante injetá-lo via contrutor. Isso deixa evidente as dependências do objeto para que ele possa realizar seu trabalho, seu código fica muito mais claro, e quando você escrever testes de unidade isso vai facilitar muito a sua vida.

Algum tempo atrás escrevi um post sobre [Spring MVC](http://www.simpledev.com.br/simplificando-springmvc.html) e outro sobre como [integrá-lo com Hibernate](http://www.simpledev.com.br/spring-hibernate.html). Dê uma olhada, creio que a parte como as dependências são injetadas podem lhe servir de exemplo.

Comment: Oi Juliano, obrigado pela resposta. Devo ser honesto com você e dizer que meu entendimento sobre injeção de dependências e até mesmo o Spring é muito pouco, pois é meu primeiro projeto no qual estou usando o framework. Entendi algumas coisas, como injeção por construtor e da maneira como eu estou instanciando o meu objeto FileController. Só não consegui entender como posso implementar essa componentização, pois caso eu faça a injeção controlada por spring do objeto de FileController dentro do meu Destinationontroler, não irá sanar minha necessidade? Abraço

Comment: Vai sim, mas de forma inapropriada, pois há uma confusão na separação de responsabilidades. A minha sugestão é, crie um objeto `ImageReplicator`, pegue o código do método `imageReplication` e mova para esse objeto e chame-o de `replicate`. Agora você pode injetar esse novo objeto e usá-lo nos seus 2 controllers! =)

Comment: Show de Bola Juliano! Matou a pau. Consegui entender e realmente é uma forma bem mais "clean" de programação. Já estou alterando a estrutura da aplicação que tenha um baixo acoplamento, assim como alterando a injeção para ser feito com construtores. Vou dar uma lida em seu blog que parece que é bem esclarecedor também. Um abraço e sucesso!